RC Plane can fly or not?
I'm making a RC Airplane using Sunboard and Cardboard. The wing is about 80cm long, with a wing profile looking like 
I also connected a A2212 1000kv Brushless motor with a 10x4.5 Inch Propeller with a 30A SimonK ESC. To power all the electronics, I used a 2200mAH 10C 3S Li-Ion battery pack. It can provide a thrust of about 600 grams. The airplane weighs about 850 grams.
Now, my question is whether the airplane can fly, since the thrust provided by the propeller is lesser than the weight of the plane.
Any help and advice would be appreciated!
Thanks!

It's very common for models with thrust less than their weight to fly, and fly well.  When I was first flying R/C (many years ago) we referred to this as "flying on the wing instead of the propeller."
Thrust need only overcome drag sufficiently to build up enough speed for the wing to generate enough lift to fly the aircraft.
Back in the late 1980s, I built a model that came out weighing 64 ounces, and it flew well and aerobatically on a .25 non-Schneurle glow engine producing nowhere near four pounds of thrust.  It wouldn't hang on the prop -- but it would do hammerheads, outside loops, and wouldn't quite sustain knife edge flight.  A pattern flier of the day would have wanted a pressure fed ball bearing Schneurle .60 producing six or seven times the power -- but they would have made their vertical maneuver much larger, too.
Your Jedelsky-like wing section probably won't fly inverted well, and it'll have limitations at low speed (it'll tend to stall sharply and without warning), but lack of power with thrust more than 2/3 the weight won't be an issue unless you want to do prop-hangs and such.

So, you believe that the plane might be able to fly?

Also,I'm not interested in doing any aerobatics or maneuvers, just simple flight. My wing dimensions and shape is appropriate right?

If you get the balance and control throws right, yes.  Go look on the Internet for Snoopy's doghouse, Superman, Wicked Witch, and flying lawnmower models.  If those can fly, something that looks like an airplane can probably fly with adjustments after a first test.

Do you have any estimate to the lift coefficient of that wing profile?

I don't, but you could very well ask that as another question.
